# Postgres database design - dashboard functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.3

I've created a star schema to store a load of social media data and supply it to a dashboard application through a series of 15 functions, which are called with a userid and date period required. The issue is that each function has, at the center of it, the same query - selecting all activity within the specified time period. The queries then aggregate the data and returns it to be displayed on the dashboard.

For example:

```
select
    poster,
    count(*) as volume
from postgres.status
where posted_date between in_date_from and in_date_to
and timeline_id = in_timeline
group by poster;
```

and another example function:

```
select
    extract(dow from posted_date) as dayofweek,
    count(*) as volume
from postgres.status
where posted_date between in_date_from and in_date_to
and timeline_id = in_timeline
group by extract(dow from posted_date);
```

It's my first time working with postgres functions and I'm hoping there's a way that I wouldn't need to essentially run this same query 15+ times for the application to refresh - it's quite a large dataset.

Comment: X/Y problem. Why do you have a star schema? Why do you *need* a function. (and: where is the function?)

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser - I think I'm storing the data in the most logic format for the kind of reporting required, and the functions are exposed as an api for the application to query with the users input. The functions are essentially as above, returning the two result columns.

Comment: You have a star schema. Is it part of a data warehouse, or can you treat it as part of a data warehouse?

Comment: Yes it is part of one

Comment: Can you *store* those aggregate values in the data warehouse? Then they'd need to be calculated only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary table for the results of your query and select its contents in your functions.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp AS SELECT ... ON COMMIT DROP; -- Your query goes here.
SELECT * FROM func_1();
SELECT * FROM func_2();
...
COMMIT;
```

You might need to use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) with e.g. [cursor variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) in the functions since caching a query plan for a temporary table might cause problems:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_1() RETURNS SETOF ... AS $$ -- Fill in your return type.
    DECLARE
        curs refcursor;
    BEGIN
        OPEN curs FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM my_temp'; -- Or the fields you need.
        FOR row IN curs LOOP
            ...
            RETURN NEXT ...;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END;
$$ STABLE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can then process the results row by row in your function and return one row at a time with [`RETURN NEXT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN58349).

Comment: Thanks - would this be an effective model for many concurrent users though? Would there be an alternative using some sort of query caching - similar to what is available in MySQL?

Comment: Temporary tables are session specific, so some data might be duplicated, but that probably can't be avoided, if the dashboard contents are user-specific. (I edited my answer to make the database automatically drop the table.) There is at least one query cache, https://code.google.com/p/pqc/ but I haven't used it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this with perm tables and a "manager" table containing the query options (date, timeline etc.) as well as the name of the table that was created.